# Why are the pronunciations of 'bicycle' and 'recycle' so different?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels, phonology, word-stress

It is obvious that both 'recycle' and 'bicycle' have a common element *'cycle'*. 'Cycle' on its own is pronounced with a long 'I' sound /aɪ/. 'Cycle' in 'recycle' is pronounced how 'cycle' is normally pronounced. That is, with a long I /aɪ/. **But** the 'cycle' in 'bicycle' is pronounced with a short 'I' sound /ɪ/ (like kit, hit, sit). In phonetic notation:

- Recycle → /riːˈsʌɪk(ə)l/
- Bicycle → /ˈbʌɪsɪk(ə)l/

Why does this happen? Can someone give some information?

Comment: Please do let me know if I need to fix anything in my post or if it is off topic or any other problem. I will check for answers tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your question. It is a surprise for me that "bicycle" is pronounced that way. I have been saying it as BAI-SAI-KUHL my whole life.

Comment: Maybe it's because the *specific* sense of ***cycle*** as used in ***bicycle*** came from French, where all the i's would be "short".  But I suspect that in [Arlo Guthrie’s *The Motorcycle Song*](https://motorcyclestudies.org/volume-14-2018/a-cultural-history-of-the-motorcycle-song-by-arlo-guthrie-misao-dean/) he only pronounces it short so ***motorsickle*** rhymes with ***pickle***.

Comment: @Sphinx you never *heard* anyone say in any movie or sing in any song /ˈbʌɪsɪk(ə)l/? I find that extraordinary.

Comment: because "e" and "i" are quite different !

Comment: simply google the famous Queen pop song for the usual pronounciation

Comment: Is this for real? Is no one seeing through this? OMG.

Comment: Cycle, cycle. Yeah, very different.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Unfortunately, the movies I watched and the songs I heard did not have "bicycle" in them. I only ever googled this word yesterday when this question was asked. I have been saying it BAI-SAI-KUHL because of English spelling. That is, it is misleading most of the time. From void's answer, I also learned that "infinite" is pronounced as IN-FIN-IT not IN-FAI-NAIT (I have been saying this wrong too!!). Learned so much from this question!

Comment: @Sphinx and yet your written English is pretty exceptional for a learner. For the benefit of ELL users,  I would like to remind them that the majority of English dictionaries online (if not all) have pronunciations written in IPA  and many also provide audio snippets.

Comment: Unicycle is pronounced like recycle, not bicycle.

Comment: The short answer is that English is a "mutt language" with influences from many other languages.  Exceptions to every rule are common.

Comment: @Sphinx I feel caught on both accounts ;-). And I think void proved me wrong (the pronunciation of *bicycle* it is at least to a degree based on discernible rules). To my defense though James' answer says essentially the same in so many words ;-).

Comment: In what dialect? Ask any english speaker to say "Scone Bone Gone" and see what happens.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket - that much is true. However, I believe that the 'cycle' part would be from the same source for both, wouldn't you? Tricycle is also from the same source. Don't think icicle is though.

Comment: @Tim Good question.  I honestly don't know.  For human-powered wheeled vehicles, I think *cycle* almost always is derived from French.  For *recycle*, I'm not sure of the origin.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This has to do with English stress patterns and prosody. English stress patterns are enormously complex and have many, many, many exceptions.

#### TL;DR

'Bicycle' has a short vowel in its second syllable because the prefix *bi-* is a stress-bearing prefix and can take primary stress (prominence). So when the primary stress moves from the *cy* to *bi-*, the *cy* gets unstressed and the diphthong [**aɪ**] gets shortened to [**ɪ**].

The diphthong in the second syllable of 'recycle' doesn't get reduced because the prefix *re-* doesn't often take primary stress, so the primary stress remains on the first syllable of *-cycle*.

### Full answer

There are two main kinds of syllables on the basis of loudness; stressed and unstressed. A stressed syllable is the prominent/loudest syllable in a word. Not all syllables in English words receive the same level of loudness (i.e. all syllables in a single word cannot have primary stress).

There are three levels of stress in English:

- **primary stressed syllable:** the loudest syllable in a word
- **unstressed syllables:** syllables that don't have stress at all
- **secondary stress:** syllables that aren't unstressed, but aren't as loud as primary-stressed syllables either (lie in between the two)

In the IPA, primary stress is represented by a preceding superscript vertical line [ˈ] while secondary stress by a preceding subscript vertical line [ˌ]. So the word *pronunciation* can be transcribed as [prəˌnʌnsiˈjeɪʃn]: the second syllable has secondary stress and the second last syllabl has primary stress.

The word 'cycle' is stressed on the first syllable and is pronounced /ˈsaɪkəl/ (with the diphthong [aɪ]).

The diphthong [**aɪ**] (as in *bite*) rarely occurs in an unstressed syllable. It has a systematic relationship with the short vowel [**ɪ**] (as in *kit*). This relationship is reflected in many words such as [*f[**aɪ**]nite - inf[**ɪ**]nite*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/259576/106592) and many other remnants of [Trisyllabic Laxing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/265606/106592); *div[**aɪ**]ne-div[**ɪ**]nity, der[**aɪ**]ve-der[**ɪ**]vative*, and in *dr[**aɪ**]ve-dr[**ɪ**]ven* etc.

From this relationship, we can infer a general rule of thumb that [aɪ] will only occur in a stressed syllable and when that syllable gets unstressed, [aɪ] will get reduced to [ɪ].

The reason why 'bicycle' is pronounced /ˈbaɪsɪkəl/ is that the prefix *bi-* is a stress-bearing prefix and can take primary stress. Also note that English has a strong tendency towards *antepenultimate stress*. It means that English words tend to be stressed on the antepenult (third-last syllable).

'Cycle' has primary stress on its first syllable and when the prefix *bi-* is prepended to it, the primary stress moves from *cy* to *bi-*, leaving the *cy* unstressed. And as I said above, when a syllable having [**aɪ**] gets unstressed, the diphthong [aɪ] usually reduces to the short vowel [ɪ]. That's what happens in *bicycle*.

*Re-* on the other hand does not often take primary stress<sup>**1**</sup>, so when it's prepended to *cycle*, the primary stress remains on the *cy*. That's why the *re-* remains unstressed and the *cy* becomes the prominent syllable.

However, the *cycle* in *unicycle, quadricycle, motorcycle* is pronounced with the diphthong [**aɪ**]. It has been explained in [this answer on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/26088/365490) [Modified]:

*motorcycle, quadricycle* and *unicycle* consist of a pair of trochees: **MO-tor-CY-cle, QUAD-ri-CY-cle, U-ni-CY-cle**. The primary stress in these words falls on the first syllable, but the secondary stress falls on the first syllable of -cycle. In this context the vowel retains its full pronunciation i.e. it still receives stress, so the diphthong doesn't get reduced.

---

**Notes:**

1. *Re-* can take primary stress in some words, as Colin Fine and Canadian Yankee pointed out in the comments below. It seems to me that disyllabic nouns that have the prefix *re-* have primary stress on the *re-*, whereas disyllabic verbs don't have primary stress on the *re-* (cf. *REcord* and *reCORD*). I think trisyllabic nouns having the prefix *re-* follow the antepenult stress rule, so they get primary stress on the *re-*.

Comment: Perhaps I am ignorant but I am not clear how that covers unicycle and quadricycle as opposed to bicycle and tricycle. I know that was not what the OP asked.

Comment: Also see [finite - infinite, potent - impotent](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/259576/106592)

Comment: _Re-_ can take primary stress, in _research_ (some pronunciations) and _reject_, but these are old words, not obviously containing the prefix _re-_, "again".

Comment: @ColinFine - In addition to your examples, I can think of other, newer words that have a stressed **re-** as initial-stress-derived nouns: **rerun**, **retread**, **redirect**, **refill**, **recount**.  I think it's just wrong to say that "*re-* can't handle initial stress," although I think you can say that it usually doesn't take stress in a verb, but it can in a noun.

Comment: @CanadianYankee: That's a good point! I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: English also often changes emphasis/pronunciation for homonyms based on whether the word is used as a noun or verb (eg., "record" - putting sound on the thing is "re-cord"-ing, but the thing is a "rec-erd" (sorry, don't know IPA at all)). I suspect something similar is happening here, too - you go "c[aɪ]cling" on a "byc[ɪ]cle", but you "rec[aɪ]cle" the thing (and, "recycle", "motorcycle", etc. are new enough that the "verb/noun" vowel shift didn't happen on creation).

Comment: Your examples _divinity, derivative, driven_ do nothing to support your argument! (Especially _driven_, which is not even trisyllabic.)

Comment: @TonyK: They do! I've used them to demonstrate the relationship between the diphthong [aɪ] and the vowel [ɪ]. And, 'driven' isn't trisyllabic,,,, I thought it would be unambiguous with the comma+and: 'div[aɪ]ne-div[ɪ]nity, der[aɪ]ve-der[ɪ]vative*, and* in dr[aɪ]ve-dr[ɪ]ven etc'.

Answer (score 14):

There's often not much point in asking why a word has a particular pronunciation. There's rarely any logic or pattern.

Recycle is a word recently created (1920s, but only being used in its modern meaning in the 1960s). It means "cycle again" and the suffix "-cycle" has the same meaning as the word (meaning to go around).

Bicycle is created on a pattern created by the earlier "tricycle" in the sense of a three-wheeled carriage. Its pronunciation was influenced by French, or rather tricycle was a word created in French and borrowed into English, and then anglicised.  Bicycle has a different stress pattern, and the suffix "-cycle" means "wheel", so a bicycle was originally an adjective "a bicycle velocipede" not a noun (the verb "to cycle" meaning to ride a bicycle is a back-formation from bicycle). So "cycle" is not really a common element. "Bicycle" is also 100 years older than recycle, so has had 100 more years for the pronunciation to be modified.  The difference in stress results in different vowels.

So the reasons are partly random, partly historical.  Essentially, they are different words which are pronounced differently, despite the similarity in spelling.

Comment: I would agree—looking at when words entered English is the right approach here. Re-cycle, and also up-cycle, have clear roots and prefixes. There are plenty of bi- words (bisexual, bifocals, bipolar, biyearly) that allow for more varied stress patterns.

Answer (score 6):

**Short Answer:**
In English, we often stress the first syllable of nouns; the second syllable for verbs.
"I went to the store and bought a RECord."
"I went to the studio to reCORD my new album."

BIcycle is a noun; reCYCLE is a verb.

Comment: This! It's a much simpler explanation of what's going on here than the other answers. And even if bicycle is used as a verb (to ride one), it's a verb formed from a noun in the sense of "to do the thing you do with that noun", and these follow the pronunciation of the noun.

Comment: Simple, but probably too simple - English pronunciation (and spelling, grammar) usually owes more to history than to logic.

Comment: "I biCYCled to the record store,"  or more commonly, "I cyCELD to the record store?"